electron-updater stops on checking for update
I'm using electron-updater 6.3.
It works fine for auto updates on Windows and Mac but I have this one Mac user who is sometimes have issues. Specifically when there are no updates available.
In that case I can see from logging out that electron-updater only get to this point (see attached screenshot).
It only gets to "Checking for update". It never reaches the "update-not-available" event.
I don't get any errors either.
I'm using Github releases. I know I'm not giving much information here but does anyone know common reasons why this would happen?

